AWS Lambda with conda python dependencies
I am currently trying to get my conda python environment to an aws lambda layer to import it in the lambda. When using pip with the precompiled pandas / numpy layer it works fine, but when using conda I run into issues.
I would generally like to use conda because of its package versioning and compability checking and would not really want to mix my conda environment with an extra pip environment only for aws.
I especially run into issues when trying to get numpy running. I am getting the error
Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package

I read online that conda packages are precompiled and aws lambda layer packages should be compiled on an aws machine. Maybe this is the issue, but other packages (e.g. redis) work without any issue.
Maybe somebody has tried using conda python packages in aws before and has some thoughts on this.
Thank you :)

Zip conda environment and upload to aws layer


Some packages are OS-dependent, so if you build the layer on your own machine, it may not work in AWS lambda due to the OS differences.  I ran into this with a different package, and to resolve it I used specific instructions when installing it locally to build the layer:
python -m pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --implementation cp --python 3.9 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade --target=the_folder_where_you_are_building_your_layer cryptography~=42.0.5

So I recommend using those sorts of options when building your layer so that you target the Python version you are using in the lambda and the --platform you are using.
Also see other similar questions/posts:

conda environment to AWS Lambda
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-python-package-compatible
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-native-libraries - this one says:


Many popular Python libraries, including NumPy and Pandas, are not
pure Python and contain code written in C or C++. When you add
libraries containing C/C++ code to your deployment package, you must
build your package correctly to ensure that it’s compatible with the
Lambda execution environment.

